# understand callback function in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to understand what `$args['id']` mean in the add_settings_section() callback function, and how the loop get the id of every section:

here my array to add sections information:

```
$ap_sections = [
    'section-theme-settings' => [
        'title'     => 'Theme settings',
        'desc'      => 'General theme settings'
    ],
    'section-styling-settings' => [
        'title'     => 'Styling settings',
        'desc'      => 'settings for editing colors, fonts and css.'
    ],
    'section-social-settings' => [
        'title'     => 'Social settings',
        'desc'      => 'Edit your social media profiles.'
    ]
];
```

here my loop:

```
foreach ( $ap_sections as $section_id => $section_value ) {
        add_settings_section( $section_id, $section_value['title'], 'ap_render_section', 'ap-theme-options' );
    }
```

and here ap_render_section callback function:

```
function ap_render_section($args) {
    global $ap_sections;
    echo '<p>' . $ap_sections[ $args['id'] ] ['desc'] . '</p>';
    echo '<hr />';
}
```

my goal is understand not copy and pate code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each section should have unique ID. And first parameter in add_settings_section function is ID of that added section. 
Check the code from [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_section):

```
add_settings_section(
    'eg_setting_section',
    'Example settings section in reading',
    'eg_setting_section_callback_function',
    'reading'
);
function eg_setting_section_callback_function( $arg ) {
    // echo section intro text here
    echo '<p>id: ' . $arg['id'] . '</p>';             // id: eg_setting_section
    echo '<p>title: ' . $arg['title'] . '</p>';       // title: Example settings section in reading
    echo '<p>callback: ' . $arg['callback'] . '</p>'; // callback: eg_setting_section_callback_function
}
```

As you can see, $arg['id'] here is "eg_setting_section". 
So, add_settings_section function passes your added unique slug and title to callback function as array elements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but in my code how the loop work on $args['id'] and how it get the id for every section

Comment: So, what is the problem there ?  echo '<p>' . $ap_sections[ $args['id'] ] ['desc'] . '</p>'; returns empty data or?